# How to configure TortoiseHg workbench to show latest changes by default?

Tags: default-settings, tortoise-hg

When I start the TortoiseHg Workbench,
nearly always I want to see what changed since the last commit.
So I wait for it to start up, then
double-click the repository in the far left "repository registry" widget,
then look at the "Revision History view" widget on the right
and click the top line "* Working directory *".

Then finally I can see
a list that shows files that changed (if any) etc.,
and in the "diff" pane the actual changes in a changed file.

I hear rumors that it is possible to change some setting to get TortoiseHg workbench on my computer to do that automatically.
How do I do that?

How do I set things up so when I start the TortoiseHg workbench, it automatically opens my favorite repository and show files in the working directory that have changed but not yet been committed (if any), etc., without any more clicking on my part?

(Is Stack Overflow a better place for this question?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The two options listed below will have TortiseHg open all the repositories you had open when you closed it and open them to the working directory revision.

Toggle the option to "Save Open Repositories On Exit" in the view menu to on.

In the TortoiseHg Settings dialog under WorkBench there is a an "Initial revision" setting, select workingdir.

[image]

[image]